# Error in passing paramters from testng.xml in testng

Tags: parameter-passing, testng, parameterized

I am unable to access paramterised value defined in testng.xml.Tried defining parameter at test and method level too which i got from other similar queries here but the erros remains same 
Error is- "Parameter 'myName' is required by @Test on method parameterTest but has not been marked @Optional or defined
in C:\Windows\Temp\testng-eclipse-281832880\testng-customsuite.xml"

Below is my snippet of code,followed by testng.xml and error

[Code snippet for one and two params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a6tv.jpg)

[testng.xml with both param types 1-at test and method level both, 2- at method level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUaYG.jpg)

Comment: Please edit you quiestion, add code exemples instead for screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me [ You just need to ensure that the same class is not being included more than once in the same `<test>` tag.

Here's a sample

```
package organized.chaos.testng;

import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class EmployeeTestNG {
    @Parameters ({"and", "abc"})
    @Test
    public void test1(String b, String a) {
        System.err.println("****" + b + a);
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters ("myName")
    public void parameterTest(String myName) {
        System.err.println("Parameterized value is " + myName);
    }
}
```

Here's the TestNG suite xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="employee-suite">
    <test name="Employee-test">
        <classes>
            <class name="organized.chaos.testng.EmployeeTestNG">
                <parameter name="myName" value="TestNG"/>
                <parameter name="and" value="KungFu"/>
                <parameter name="abc" value="Panda"/>
                <methods>
                    <include name="parameterTest"/>
                    <include name="test1"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here's the output

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /Users/krmahadevan/githome/PlayGround/testbed/src/test/resources/employee.xml
Parameterized value is TestNG
****KungFuPanda

===============================================
employee-suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: yes thanx Krishnan i used once only the class name under <test> tag.. it worked for me the problem was i was running through class..When i ran through XML configuration it worked for me

Comment: @SAMINATAJ - if my answer helped you, can you please help accept it ?